# MENSA IQ Test and rules of maths

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

In a *Mensa calendar, A daily challenge* - `your daily brain workout`. I got this and put a challenge up at work.

The Challenge starts with..

```
Assume you are using a basic calculator and press the numbers in the order shown,
replacing each question mark ...continues... What is the highest number you can 
possibly score?
```

Basically, only using $+,-, * ,\div$, **once** in place of a question mark.

> $5 ? 4 ? 7 ? 3 ? 2 =$

We all worked out the operators to be

> $5 + 4 $ x $ 7 - 3/2 =$

### **Except that I calculated the answer to be $31.5$ and the others argued $30$. THe answer sheet from MENSA says the calculated total is 30.**

Nobody actually understood the first part about using a basic calculator. I initially thought the challenge was all about the rules of maths.
And when I asked why nobody else applied the rules of maths, they all forgot about it, not because the challenge said to use some "basic calculation"

I emailed MENSA and queried them about the challenge and they replied,

```
Thank you for your email.

On a basic calculator it will be:
5 + 4 = 9
9 x 7 = 63
63 – 3 = 60
60 ÷ 2 = 30

Kind regards,
Puzzle Team
```

My Reply,

```
 Thank you for your reply. 

 Could you please define what a basic calculator is? I tried 4 pocket,
 £1 calculators, and all gave me 31.5.
```

And finally their definition.

```
I guess what the question really means, whether you do the sum manually or on a 
calculator,  is don’t change the order of the numbers. The Casio calculators we have in 
the office allow you to do the sum as it appears:

5 + 4 = 9
9 x 7 = 63
63 – 3 = 60
60 ÷ 2 = 30

Kind regards,
Puzzle Team
```

So they **guess** the challenge meant to do it that way. Why not just say ignore rules of maths. What is the point of this anyway?

---

My original question, on Maths Stack (this one) was why MENSA used 30 instead of 31.5. And initially I did not understand that using a basic calculator meant calculating left to right by pressing equals after each operation.

So what is going on here? If they wanted us the ignore rules of math they should of said taht. Because my basic calculator gives me 31.5 and not 30.0 (I dont have a special. Casio MENSA calculator though)

Windows standard calculator gives me 30. Why? None of my pocket, office, el cheapo calculators do this.

[image]

Google, or Windows Scientific give me 31.5 - As do ally my elelctornic calculators.

[image]

Comment: Windows calculator gave me 11 though...

Comment: Seriously. I type in `5 + 2 * 3` in that order and get 21. I change to Scientific Calc and i get 11???? WHat about the MENSA question. is it 30 or 31.5?

Comment: Technically, the rule isn't "multiplication before division" and "subtraction before adding". It's "multiplication and division before addition and subtraction", performed left to right. But that's really just a convention we learn as kids. In any serious mathematical pursuit, parentheses are utilized to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Yea you right. I wasn't very good at remember rhymes... But at least my maths was correct :P

Comment: @ppumkin - Before finishing reading your question or any of the answers I wanted to work out the problem myself.  I got **31.5**.  So you aren't alone!  Maybe it's due to my profession of being a developer/programmer, but I always have had it ingrained in my mind the rule of operations: ***left*** to ***right***, _multiplication_ and _division_ ***before*** _addition_ and _subtraction_.

Comment: Before we bring out the pitchforks, it might be relevant to ask how the rules were written. Perhaps the rules stated that the calculation **should** be carried as on a classical pocket calculator, ie naively from left to right, evaluated at each step. Ie, maybe this was meant as a "pocket calculator riddle".

Comment: I saw the facebook quiz results with basic math (order of operations) and thought "surely they must all be trolling..."  The apocalypse really is drawing near!

Comment: @nitro2k01 I will check tomorrow, but I don't remember anything like that. Maybe the wording insinuate this... But I re read it several times and did not catch that. But maybe you are correct, that is why its marked as hardest... sly :)

Comment: In the Windows calculator (Windows 7 here), oddly enough, if you have it in Standard mode, it gives 21, and if you have it in Scientific or Programmer, it gives 11 (unless you type 5+2 **[Enter]** *3[Enter], which results in 21)

Comment: idk if this is even relevant, but the mnemonic we used to learn order of operations is PEMDAS which would seem to contradict what you stated about "subtraction before addition". i figure this may not be relevant but wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: Order of operations isn't a rule of mathematics, it's just a notational convention. There is nothing wrong with using a different notational convention, except for the confusion it causes. The problem with the question is that it doesn't specify what convention you need to follow.

Comment: [The Order of Operations is Wrong - minutephysics - youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9h1oqv21Vs)

Comment: I got a reply from mensa. The question does actually say `using a basic calculator` - i have replied asking them to define what a basic calculator is.

Comment: I am not allowed to rewrite the question here. Sorry, its so clever its copyrighted. But the actual equation cannot be copyrighted

Comment: @TimS. They either got a bug in their calculator, or seriously f**cked up logic.

Comment: @ppumkin there's something called "fair use" about copyrighted material... and you can always tell us what was the original question, without using their exact words.

Comment: Well, you have to remember that MENSA is just a stupid company like any other company in the world, and that IQ is defined as the ability to pass IQ tests. The correllation of IQ with intelligence is unknown.

Comment: I don't see where you mention the goal of having the highest result possible in your question. I figured it out from the comments/responses. Did you edit or am I blind?

And now to the point. I do not understand what all the fuss is about. You seem to have a problem with the definition of a basic calculator. For me on the other hand it is quite obvious. They could have of course formulate the problem better, because the question actually checks the understanding of what the basic calculator is instead of IQ, but it seems to me that you are asking a wrong question here...

Comment: @MichalB. Sorry I put in the actual question. Forgot to write about what is the highest "score" the word score itself is weird? My issue is that no matter what a sentence says. Maths only has 1 set of rules, that is what I was taught all my life. **The only way to change order of calculation is using brackets.** It doesnt matter what the question or challenge says. In our world we only have 1 kind of maths and set of rules. Unless aliens invade us and reveal there are actually x times more kinds of maths, even MENSA should not be able to change the rules of maths.

Comment: @ppumpkin: I think you are wrong. They don't ask you to solve a mathematical problem. You are asked for the highest score you can get by executing a well-defined set of actions on a basic calculator.

Comment: @ppumkin "Maths only has 1 set of rules, that is what I was taught all my life.", I'm sorry to disappoint you, but the standard order of calculation is only a wide-spread convention and nothing more. Should someone wish to define a different order of calculation, he is free to do so (it would be _weird_, but it wouldn't be _wrong_). And, in this case, I suspect that was the intention of author of the puzzle. In other words, your expression should be $(((5\ ?\ 4)\ ?\ 7)\ ?\ 3)\ ?\ 2$; "using a basic calculator" is just a commonly used phrase to describe that, not one to be understood literally.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In response to edit of initial post, then answer is clearly $30$. Basic calculators are assumed to evaluate in order from left to right.

---

**Original post I responded to**

In a Mensa calander, IQ dialy challenge I got this and put a challenge up at work.

Using +,-,time and divide only once. Use the math operator only once to get the highest answer.

> 5 ? 4 ? 7 ? 3 ? 2 =

We all worked out

> 5 + 4 x 7 - 3 / 2 = 30

Except that my result answer was 31.5 and not 30, like in the answers of the MENSA calendar.

Why was I the only one that applied the rules of maths on this? ANd when I asked why nobody else applied the rule of maths, I got the weirdest looks. **Nobody knew about multiplication before division, subtraction before adding?**  I thought that was why the question was marked as the most difficutl to test if you knew this.

---

**Response to original post**

Sadly, many people forget the basic rules of arithmetic as they (a) don't view them as affecting their lives, (b) didn't like maths, and/or (c) know technology can handle the problem for them. The issue with the last point is that different technologies handle things differently. The Google calculator (much like most graphing calculators) will handle order of operations for you correctly. The standard Windows calculator appears to be operating like an old 4 function calculator which evaluates after every operation is completed as opposed to correct order of operations. Though this can also happen when users hit enter after every operation is finished as opposed to when the whole expression is finished. (Don't have access to a Windows calculator right now so can't tell which is the reason for the wrong answer.)

Comment: What about the mesna question... is the answer 30? or 31.5? Did they also use a Windows calculator? lol

Comment: @ppumkin Your expression certainly evaluates to $31.5$.

Comment: MENSA is wrong? Im want a refund.

Comment: MENSA is full of people and people make mistakes.

Comment: Frankly, I think the calendar was "dumbed down" because most people would naturally evaluate left-to-right regardless of the order of operations.

Comment: Yea - That is fine, but MENSA claims to have the top something percent of the smartest people in the world. And I no longer look up to MESNA because they made me look dumb in front of my colleagues.

Comment: @Roger But its incorrect! Wrong. The question was not even based on rules of maths, just dumb addition for pre school chidren.

Comment: Most printed material also goes through editors who may make changes to the "right" answer their calculator gave them.

Comment: Possibly. I know a bit about that.Anm original sentence might come out like gargling if you don't notice it before publishing.  Ehh. It surprised me the NONE of my colleagues knew about Rules of Maths. And some of them after UNI! Makes me want to cry. And I work as a software developer.

Comment: @ppumkin Welcome to the club (of those who want to cry about this). As an educator, I see this way too often in the US.

Comment: I feel sorry for you. Statistically 1 in 10 (in my organization) people know about this... That 1 was me. But hey, now 10 in 10 know about and I hope they flippin remember! I might be getting underpaid...

Comment: Just as long as they remember that you are smarter than the MENSA calendar the next time they disagree with you in a meeting.

Comment: Sorry for changing my question mid way. I never knew calculators worked from left to right. All my calculations give me 31.5- and they are the cheap, non scientific ones.

Answer (score 11):

You are indeed correct in that we apply multiplication and division before addition and subtraction.

However, multiplication and division have the same precedence, as does addition and subtraction. When multiplication and division (or addition and subtraction) are both part of an expression, we evaluate which ever appears first (when reading from left to right).

> "When do I apply what?"

The good old "order of operations, once again:

1. Parentheses or brackets. Perform the part of the expression enclosed in parentheses or brackets, first, working from innermost to outermost. $$50/[5 \times (2 + 3)] = 2$$
2. Exponents. Then take powers of a term. $(2+3)^2 / 3 = (5)^2/3 = \frac{25}{3}$.
3. multiplication and division (performed from left to right). 
   $8/4 \times 3 = 2\times 3$, $8\times 4/3 = \frac{32}{3}$
4. addition and subtraction (performed from left to right)

Comment: I don't understand. In school they taught me (Drilled me for 16 years) to always create virtual brackets (first multiplication, then division, then...) etc etc. Power come before multiplication, i learnt that in UNI. And that, ALWAYS use rules of maths. This is not grammar?!?! It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @ppumkin For example, the expression $4/2*8 = 16 \neq \frac{4}{16}$.

Comment: OK Thanks. I knew that. So there is absolutely no way that we should add before multiply, in no circumstance? Is MENSA wrong?

Comment: Your computations, in your post, are correct! (It just so happens that in the post, multiplication appears before division, and addition before subtraction, when read from left to right.)

Comment: Yea what about adding and sbutraction @JohnHabert . put that in there and which comes first

Comment: The problem is why is MENSA saying 30, instead of 31.5?

Comment: @ppumkin It is exactly as amWhy as listed. But as an example $4/2*8-2*6+5 = 16-12+5=4+5=9$

Comment: Addition and subtraction have the same precedence: whichever occurs "before" the other in an expression is performed first.  $8-4 + 2= 6$ (Note: $8 - 4 + 2 \neq 2)$.

Comment: Thanks for you very good answer. I marked Johns answer correct because he was first, and yea - it is all human error really.

Comment: Where is Aunt Sally and why did she not answer this question herself?

Comment: @corsiKa Is that as in "My Dear Aunt Sally"? (Or, how about: "Dear, My Silly Aunt!")

Comment: @amWhy yes, "Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally" is how we were taught to remember the order. Naturally, we can excuse her for not answering the question, since that's what we've been taught to do.

Comment: So Mensa replied and said the question contains the term to use a basic calculator. ANy thoughts- because that just sounds mad to me.

Comment: Sounds mad to me to, ppukin! Mensa, of all people!

Answer (score 11):

With the edits you've made to your question, it's now clear — at least to the older generation — that MENSA's answer is correct and yours is not.

The point is that the challenge does *not*, as you seem to think, ask you to replace the question marks in:

```
5 ? 4 ? 7 ? 3 ? 2 =
```

with the operators `+`, `−`, `×` and `÷` in any order, and then to evaluate the resulting string as a mathematical expression according to the rules of arithmetic.  If that's what they'd meant, that's what they would've written.  Rather, what the challenge *literally* tells you to do (*emphasis*  mine) is:

> "Assume you are using a *basic calculator* and press the numbers in the order shown,
>   replacing each question mark..."

In context, it should be clear that, by "basic calculator" they mean a classic [4-function pocket calculator](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_calculator) (as opposed to a fancy modern [formula calculator](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_calculator)) like [this one](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aSolar-calculator.jpg):

[image]

These kinds of calculators traditionally had no memory to store complicated expressions (and no way to enter or, indeed, display anything like parentheses), so they used [immediate execution](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculator_input_methods): they would only have enough memory to store two numbers and an operator, and every time you pressed an operator button (`+`, `−`, `×`, `÷` or `=`), the previously chosen operator would be applied to combine the two stored numbers into one.  (The function of the `=` button was simply to perform the last operation and show the result without queuing any new operation.)

Effectively, such calculators thus evaluated all expressions stricly from left to right, ignoring arithmetic precedence; the sequence of button presses `5 ? 4 ? 7 ? 3 ? 2 =` would be evaluated as `(((5 ? 4) ? 7) ? 3) ? 2 =` regardless of the operators the `?` marks stood for.

Of course, this is a pretty limited method of computation: for example, there's no way to directly calculate an expression like `(2 * 3) + (4 * 5)` on such a calculator.  As a limited workaround, most pocket calculators did include an extra memory slot into which the user could store an intermediate result for later recall.  (That's what the "M−" and "M+" buttons in the picture are for.)  Of course, if you needed more than one such intermediate result, you'd better have either some paper and a pencil handy, or just a good memory.  Still, it was the best you could do cheaply using 1970's technology, so people learned to live with the limitations.

Comment: I cant even find one of those calculators. The only thing that emulates that is the standard windows calculator. I did not even know about this issue until now. I just cannot find one of those calculators anywhere, with immediate execution. So really, the user of those calculators had to input the numbers in the correct order. SO yes, that opening statements makes sense. BUt like you said, its age related. I had no idea that is what they meant. Wow. What a question

Comment: You could probably find some *really* cheap Chinese-made ones, possibly solar-powered like the one in the picture, still sold in places like dollar stores. They still have a marginal market niche with people who want something very small, very cheap and very low-powered, and don't mind skimping on functionality to achieve it. Oh, and of course older folks who are just used to them.

Comment: 4-function calculators are definitely still around (though not as common as scientifics and graphing ones these days).  I actually have one i bought from Wal-Mart last year (~$10), because they were allowed in calculus even where the fancier calculators weren't.  It was one of maybe a half dozen different brands/sizes at the time -- and that's not even counting the adding machines, which work much the same way but can print as well.

Comment: Yea this is definitely the answer I was looking for. Taking into account that you knew about the 4 functional - calculator, you wouldn't bother applying the rules.I had no idea about this and straight away started to play with arrangements of the signals based on rules, ignorantly,ignoring the very first sentence because of lack of knowledge. What makes it even more interesting is that whether you apply the rules or not, the signs are valid in both ways- which was the essence of the challenge. It sure stirred up a storm...

Comment: The models we were allowed in high school worked that way. It had support for parentheses, though. (Yea, no auomated graphing and similar stuff for us.)

Comment: Typing in "pocket calculator" in the search field at Amazon will give you a lot of them. I guess these calculators became less popular, because pretty much every mobile phone has some calculator.

Answer (score 4):

Just to play devil's advocate and give MENSA the benefit of the doubt since we don't have the actual question. Maybe for the following reasons, 30 can be THE valid answer:

1. The actual sequence of operators does not change whether it is 30 or 31.5, which is the key for getting the right response.
2. There is a difference between IQ and simply knowing rules. Figuring out how to get to 30 takes a keen eye and a bit of thought (calculators not allowed for MENSA test). e.g. imagine this a multiple choice question without the answer 31.5.

Comment: Yes- I think you are right. THis question must have been developed by generations of mensa members, to make it correct and incorrect at the same time. But the truth is, maths doesn't lie- and there is only 1 answer to a maths equation, otherwise we would life a life of goo. I don't think I would get along with people at MENSA. Hahaha

Comment: A better multiple choice question would include the answer 31.5 just to throw you off.

Answer (score 3):

I have just seen your update to the question with the reply from Mensa.

The question setters are trying too hard. It's the case that you need to be able to think like them to get the right answer rather than being intelligent. If they meant that the calculator ignores rules of precedence then they should state that explicitly as a basic calculator can mean many things and doesn't have to exclude rules of precedence as computing is very cheap compared to the 80's when a basic calculator might be expected to ignore precedence.

Do you really want to join such a club?

Comment: Yea exactly y thoughts. both on the calculator bit and whether I want to join such a club. Besides this is not an IQ test calendar...? Its a public challenge based on your intelligence. This is what is annoying me off.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Our mnemonic was "MDAS" but we didn't interpret it as addition before subtraction. It was multiplication and division before addition and subtraction, as others have pointed out.

So, evaluating 5 + 4 x 7 − 3 / 2 would be:

- 5 + 4 x 7 - 3 / 2
- 5 +  28   - 3 / 2
- 5 +  28   - 1.5
- 33 - 1.5
- 31.5

Comment: It could as well be `DMSA`, you just couldn't spell it. If you have both a Multiplication and a Division, you calculate them from left to right. Just as John Harbert stated in a previous comment: $4/2*8 = 16 \neq \frac{4}{16}$

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is neither 30 nor 31.5 but +×−÷.

I have never seen MENSA calendar but you stated “like in the answers of the MENSA calendar.” Did you mean readers' or publisher's answers? The first would be amusing, the second would be appalling.

Anyway, being smarter than the average MENSA enthusiast is something one welcomes rather than complaining about.

Comment: Are you ready. The publishers answer actually says `5+4*7-3/2=30` That is the answer. I answered `5+4*7-3/2=31.5` which makes me incorrect. Are you crying yet, laughter or from grief?

Comment: The question is biased so that cleverness is challenged by Casio calculators that some people have in the office. _Something is rotten in the state of_ MENSA.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your work mates were amazed by your stunning mathematical ability, isn't the highest answer possible actually 61.5?

Comment: It would be better if you said how you think that result would be achieved.

Comment: He obviously solved (5 + 4) x 7 − 3/2 = 61.5  If you are going there, you should probably go all the way to: (5 + 4) x 7 / (3 - 2) = 63

Comment: Lol. This must be one of my old work colleague . Hehehe, is that you Gaz? lol. Problem is that we were not allowed to use brackets. Just replace `?` with the operators provided, not reconstruct the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

`5+4*7-3/2` **The** [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=5%2b4%20x%207%E2%88%923/2#q=5%2b4%2a7-3/2) agreed with me.

Yes, order of operations is Multiple and Divide first:

`5+(4*7)-(3/2)` = 31.5

So then, you want to multiply the two biggest numbers you can and have the largest denominator as possible when subtracting or smallest denominator as possible when adding.  You **could** do an [proof by exhaustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion) since the dataset is small:

```
5+4-7*3/2 = -1.5
5+4-7/3*2 = 4.33
5+4*7-3/2 = 31.5
5*4+7-3/2 = 25.5
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

But parentheses weren't allowed in the original question so you cannot apply them selectively. You either work with mdas rules (implied parentheses) or the primitive left to right calc. Thus neither 61.5 nor 63 are valid.

Comment: Where did you get 61 from? Yes- It seems like they wanted us to do left to right... using a basic calculator. but they cant actually tell me what a basic calculator is. It must be what you're saying. Its so clever it makes me want to cry.

Comment: Presumably, this should've been a comment to [user128049's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/672808).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a fair assumption that the rules of math should be applied to a mathematical expression.

Btw, it is not stated (but I guess it's implied) that the operators must be put in place of the question marks, or else

-5/4+7*32 = 222.75

Comment: By that logic the max is 54732. Just don't use any operators.

Comment: Yes, if "Using +,−,∗,÷ only once each" is taken to mean "at most once" rather than "exactly once". I used the latter interpretation but now that you bring it up it's not entirely clear to me which is correct (I'm not a native speaker).

Answer (score -3):

the answer is 31.5. you know it but you messed up the math.
with subtraction and addition it shouldnt matter which is carried out first; they can both be considered to be identical functions (addition of a positive and a negative no or vice versa)

the answer is therefore 28+5-1.5; whichever way you look at it.